# Find out probability that the annual precipitation will be between 90cm and 102 cm?

Tags: probability

The standard normal probability function can be approximated as

$$F(X_N)= 
\frac{1}{(1+\exp(-1.7255X_N|X_N|^{0.12})}$$
Where

$X_N$=  standard normal  deviation .

If  mean and standard deviation of annual precipitation are 102 cm and 27 cm  respectively, the probability that the annual precipitation will be between 90 and 102 cm is?

Answer is 16.7%
In this problem . Im not getting function properly.

Comment: Please learn to format your posts. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standardized limits for you interval are:
$$
\begin{aligned}
z_1&=\frac{90-102}{27}=-0.4444..\\
z_2&=\frac{102-102}{27}=0
\end{aligned}
$$
Then using your approximation for the cumulative standard normal the required probability is:
$$
P=F(z_2)-F(z_1)=F(0) - F(0.4444)=0.16723
$$

Compared to a probability of 0.17162 using the actual cumulative standard normal.

Matlab anonomous function definition of your approximation:

```
ff=@(x) 1./(1+exp(-1.7255*x.*abs(x).^0.12));
```

Comment: Will this F(0) and F(0.4444) solved by above given equation.? And then it will become = 0.16723.

Comment: @akash $F(0.4444)=0.33277$, $F(0)=0.5$, and $0.5-0.33277=0.16723$

Comment: Sir why are you comparing standard cumulative normal to its actual. What you want to show ?

Comment: Sir I've  got whatever you wrote.but last line ..compared to probability of .17162 using actual cumulative standard normal ...i dont get

Comment: @akash The answer using your approximation gives an approximate answer for the probability. I compare this with the result of using the actual cumulative standard normal because I am interested in the accuracy of the approximation and because I can.